# Error in installing OpenInviter [gmail, yahoomail contacts importer]

Tags: php, sqlite, openinviter

How to define stats username and password in sqlite3?

I am using the sqlite3 database and openinviter tool. While installing the tool, I encounter the following error.

> SQLite is installed. Stats enabled. Please define a stats username and password in config.php

- Checking username and private key...   *OK*
- Checking PHP version... *OK*
- Checking DOMDocument support... *OK*
- Checking transport method... libcurl is installed. Using cURL to handle
  requests
- **SQLite is installed. Stats enabled. Please define a stats username and 
  password in  config.php**
- Checking   write permisions... /tmp
  is writable. Using /tmp to store
  cookie files and  logs

Answer (score 0):

You have to `nano config.php` from the director for OpenInviter (the same directory where you ran postinstall.php to get the results above.

In config.php you'll see the config options for sqlite username and password.

Hope that helps even though it's way late!